# Scrolling to an element on click

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've got the following problem:

I've got a button:

```
<div id="meerinfotoestel">
   <a id="scroll-to-meerinfo" href="#meerinfo">
      Meerinfo
   </a>
</div>
```

And I've got some tabs setup with the following name:

`.woocommerce-tabs`

Now I want the screen to scroll to the tabs, onclick.

I've got the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#scroll-to-meerinfo').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    scrollToElement('.woocommerce-tabs');
});
</script>
```

Apparently the only thing that this does is put an anchor after the url.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You can try to borrow some concepts from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: This should help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316027/jquery-jscrollpanes-scrolltoelement

Comment: @LodewijkWensveen - Then, please tell us, how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Ofcourse, I took this code from the first link provided:  $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#click").click(function (){
            //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                     }, 2000);
            //});
        });
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#scroll-to-meerinfo').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#woocommerce-tabs').scrollIntoView(true);
      // let your tab id is woocommerce-tabs
    });
});
```

**Syntax of scrollIntoView**

```
element.scrollIntoView(alignWithTop);
```

Read Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

Comment: TypeError: $(...).scrollIntoView is not a function

Comment: Do you add `id attribute` in your `tab`?

Answer (score 1):

See this:  **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/snd5w/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#scroll-to-meerinfo').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    scrollToElement($('.woocommerce-tabs'));
  });

  function scrollToElement(elem) {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: elem.offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```